# Grid Template auto sizing a row is not working

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to auto resize a row but it isn't resizing. How can I make the row adjust height automatically?

My code:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px red, inset -2px -2px red
}

.body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 40px;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

.body div {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px red, inset -2px -2px red
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
  /* works if I but "calc(100vh - 120px)" in place of 'auto'*/
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="pageHead">Head</div>
      <div class="pageContent">Content</div>
      <div class="pageFoot">Foot</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ypnNav">
      Nav
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Why isn't auto working? I have also tried 1fr in place of auto but that too doesn't work.

What is the right way of tackling such situation in 'grid-template-areas'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost good, you simply need to add `flex-grow:1` to `.body` to fill the space of the flex container you set within the `body`. Your code is working fine but the issue is on an upper container.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px red, inset -2px -2px red
}

.body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 40px;
  flex-grow: 1; /*added*/
}

.body div {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px red, inset -2px -2px red
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="pageHead">Head</div>
    <div class="pageContent">Content</div>
    <div class="pageFoot">Foot</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ypnNav">
    Nav
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also simplify like below and avoid an extra wrapper:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 40px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px red, inset -2px -2px red
}

body div {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px red, inset -2px -2px red
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="pageHead">Head</div>
  <div class="pageContent">Content</div>
  <div class="pageFoot">Foot</div>
</div>
<div class="ypnNav">
  Nav
</div>
```

Using `display:contents` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) you can still simplify more:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr 40px 40px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px red, inset -2px -2px red
}

body div {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px red, inset -2px -2px red
}

.page {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="pageHead">Head</div>
  <div class="pageContent">Content</div>
  <div class="pageFoot">Foot</div>
</div>
<div class="ypnNav">
  Nav
</div>
```